# Concatenate files on linux with Gradle

Tags: linux, bash, groovy, gradle

Here's my current Gradle task :

```
task concat << {
    println "cat $localWebapp/sc*.js > $buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"
    exec {
        commandLine "bash","-c",'cat',"$localWebapp/sc*.js", ">", "$buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"
    }
}
```

Even while the command I print using `println` is correct (it's working if I paste it in a console in the project directory), the command doesn't build the `sc.concat.js` file.

What's happening and how can I fix that ?

Comment: shouldn't this be `commandLine "bash","-c","cat "$localWebapp/sc*.js > $buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"` (all in one param for the shell)?

Comment: @cfrick Yes, you're right. I thought I had tested it but I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh -c` takes one param for the script/commands to execute:

```
commandLine "/bin/sh","-c","cat $localWebapp/sc*.js > $buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"
```

Otherwise the params after `cat` are passed as further params to shell, which are "misinterpreted".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `commandLine`, it seems `executable` works:

```
task concat << {
    println "cat $localWebapp/sc*.js > $buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"
    exec {
        executable "sh"
        args "-c", "cat $localWebapp/sc*.js > $buildDir/js/sc.concat.js"
    }
}
```